# LINQ query to include fields from one row of a child table

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, linq

I'm trying to work out how to use a LINQ query to return details from the main entity, as well as detail from one row from a 1-to-Many (or 0..1-to-Many) child entity.

The details here are just a simplified example. It's more the concept I'm looking for. The Entity Framework classes might be defined as:

```
public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Department { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Login> Logins { get; set; }
}

public class Login
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime LoginTimestamp { get; set; }
    public string IpAddress { get; set; }
    public string UserAgent { get; set; }

    public virtual User User { get; set; }
}
```

So starting the query, I'd want something like:

```
var results = from u in Users
    select new {u.Id, u.Name, u.Email, u.Department}
```

All good so far. Say I wanted to add the last login date and time:

```
var results = from u in Users
    select new {u.Id, u.Name, u.Email, u.Department, u.Logins.Max(LoginTimestamp)}
```

Still good. But now I want to add further details from the latest login record. Say I also want to include the IP Address from the last login as well. I know the query is going to have to change substantially and use something other than "Max", but I'm not sure how. Joins? Sub-queries?

I've seen reference to doing something like this:

```
var results = from u in Users
    select new {u.Id, u.Name, u.Email, u.Department, 
        u.Logins.Max(LoginTimestamp), 
        u.Logins.OrderByDescending(LoginTimestamp).FirstOrDefault().IPAddress}
```

... but I suspect thats very inefficient, and increasingly so for each further column added from the child entity.

What's the best/most efficient way to do this?

Just to be clear, I only want one row in the resultset for each user, to include details of the last login only.

Thanks

**EDIT 16 June 2016:**

I've built this example, and used LINQPad to test the query.

For this LINQ query:

```
from u in Users
    select new {u.Id, u.Name, u.Email, u.Department, 
        LastLogin = u.Logins.OrderByDescending(l => l.LoginTimestamp).FirstOrDefault().LoginTimestamp, 
        LastIP = u.Logins.OrderByDescending(l => l.LoginTimestamp).FirstOrDefault().IpAddress}
```

... the SQL it produces is ...

```
SELECT 
    [Project2].[Id] AS [Id], 
    [Project2].[Name] AS [Name], 
    [Project2].[Email] AS [Email], 
    [Project2].[Department] AS [Department], 
    [Project2].[C1] AS [C1], 
    [Limit2].[IpAddress] AS [IpAddress]
    FROM   (SELECT 
        [Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], 
        [Extent1].[Name] AS [Name], 
        [Extent1].[Email] AS [Email], 
        [Extent1].[Department] AS [Department], 
        (SELECT TOP (1) [Project1].[LoginTimestamp] AS [LoginTimestamp]
            FROM ( SELECT 
                [Extent2].[LoginTimestamp] AS [LoginTimestamp]
                FROM [dbo].[Logins] AS [Extent2]
                WHERE [Extent1].[Id] = [Extent2].[User_Id]
            )  AS [Project1]
            ORDER BY [Project1].[LoginTimestamp] DESC) AS [C1]
        FROM [dbo].[Users] AS [Extent1] ) AS [Project2]
    OUTER APPLY  (SELECT TOP (1) [Project3].[IpAddress] AS [IpAddress]
        FROM ( SELECT 
            [Extent3].[LoginTimestamp] AS [LoginTimestamp], 
            [Extent3].[IpAddress] AS [IpAddress]
            FROM [dbo].[Logins] AS [Extent3]
            WHERE [Project2].[Id] = [Extent3].[User_Id]
        )  AS [Project3]
        ORDER BY [Project3].[LoginTimestamp] DESC ) AS [Limit2]
```

... which is isn't particularly efficient, and it only going to get worse as it appears to add a sub-query for each field output from the (same) child entity.

If I was doing this in SQL, I would use:

```
SELECT Users.Id, Users.Name, Users.Email, Users.Department, Logins.LoginTimestamp, Logins.IpAddress, Logins.UserAgent
FROM (SELECT MAX(LoginTimestamp) AS LastLoginTimestamp, User_Id
          FROM Logins AS Logins_1
          GROUP BY User_Id) AS LastLogins INNER JOIN
      Logins ON LastLogins.LastLoginTimestamp = Logins.LoginTimestamp AND LastLogins.User_Id = Logins.User_Id INNER JOIN
      Users ON Logins.User_Id = Users.Id
```

One subquery, and you can bring in as many fields from the child table as necessary.

So I guess my question is how to replicate this SQL query in LINQ?

Alternatively, if there is a more efficient way of doing this through LINQ, I'd love to see it.

Any help appreciated!
Thanks

Comment: There is nothing wrong with this, the sql will optimize out to the correct joins which should limit all the sub parts down to easily managed chunks. I suppose your login table could go to a million records but then its more a matter of managing the data retention more then micro-optimizing the query. IMO, take with a  grain of salt, YMMV and so on.

Comment: agree with @PaulSwetz. You should consider to had a `LastLogin` property to your `User`. This LastLogin begin populated (by a FK to the logins table) on each insert in the logins table.

Comment: @PaulSwetz - the approach certainly worked, but having analysed the SQL via LinqPad in my particular application it appears to build a subquery for each field brought in from the child entity which is what I expected. Using SQL directly, you'd use all necessary fields from the same query, so it doesn't appear to have optimized it fully. Which brings me back to the question - is there a better/more efficient way of doing it?
(When I get 5, I'll build an application based on this example just to confirm my findings and conclusion!)

Comment: @tschmit077 - I really like this approach, and I'm going to use it where appropriate. Thanks!
However, it solves the scenario in this particular example. What if I need something a bit more flexible? Perhaps I need the last login within a particular time range, or last login from a specific IPAddress etc?
Although I included this example, the question was more conceptual - I'd be interested in a more dynamic approach where the child-row of interest could be dependant on a number of factors defined at runtime, and therefore can't be stored as a pointer in the parent entity.

Comment: Entitiy Framework is for people who don't need to worry about speed (because you have no direct control over the SQL being generated). If you need speed, consider writing a SQL Stored Procedure, and calling that from EF instead.

Comment: @buffjape - I take your point, and I don't disagree with your suggestion. However, just as there are ways to rewrite SQL queries to optimize them, this question is about optimizing the LINQ query, not ultimate performance. I'm not particularly worried about speed, but I don't want to be unnecessarily wasteful when it comes to the processing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can avoid the double subquery using `let`

```
var result = from u in Users
             let lastLogin = u.Logins.OrderByDescending(l => l.LoginTimestamp).FirstOrDefault()
             select new {u.Id, u.Name, u.Email, u.Department, 
                    LastLogin = lastLogin.LoginTimestamp,
                    LastIP = lastLogin.IpAddress};
```

Comment: Thanks. I like this approach. Clear, flexible, does the job. (LINQPad confirms the optimization in the SQL produced). +1 from me - Thanks!

Comment: Can you please hele me with this linq query:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40288901/linq-query-giving-me-inappropriate-output-while-counting-inner-child-elements

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
var results = from u in Users
    select new {u.Id, u.Name, u.Email, u.Department,     
    Logins.Where(l=>l.User.Id==u.Id).LastOrDefault()}
```

I guess Login Id is Auto-Increment.If so,LastOrDefault() will return last login od the user

Comment: Thanks Mehmet. I realise how close I was with my original query.
I would make one small change just to remove the requirement for the Where clause, and remove reliance on an auto-increment ID: LastLogin = u.Logins.OrderByDecending(l => l.LoginTimestamp).FirstOrDefault(). Otherwise the SQL it produces is exactly as I would want, and the same as the answer by @Jamiec. In terms of readability, I find Jamiec's answer a bit easier, with the added bonus of being able to specify which columns to draw through, but obviously everyone will have their preference. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To provide two more solutions to my own question...

Both reverse perspective in that the queries approach the problem from the context of the Logins, instead of the User as both previous answers have done.
They are very similar, but slight variations of each other.

Method 1:

```
from l in Logins
// where clause here
group l by l.User.Id into grp
let LastLogin = grp.Max(ul => ul.LoginTimestamp)
from l in grp
where l.LoginTimestamp == LastLogin
select new { l.User.Id, l.User.Name, l.User.Email, l.User.Department, LastLogin }
```

Method 2:

```
from l in Logins
// where clause here
group l by l.User.Id into grp
let ul = grp.OrderByDescending(ul => ul.LoginTimestamp).FirstOrDefault()
select new { ul.User.Id, ul.User.Name, ul.User.Email, ul.User.Department, LastLogin = ul.LoginTimestamp }
```

The SQL produced by method 1 looks cleaner and better optimized than method 2, but still don't quite match the previous two answers. For that reason, I still prefer the answer by Jamiec.

In any case, maybe these two alternatives will be useful to someone.

Answer (score -1):

You can get the generated SQL in each case by calling `ToString()` for each Entity Framework query. Than you can examine it's efficiency.

If, by mistake, you've somewhere used `Enumerable` extensions instead of EF and `Queryable` ones (that translate into single SQL query) you will see this.

Comment: Thanks @stop-cran. I wasn't able to do this - perhaps it's down to the specifics queries I'm running. However, it did prompt me to download LinqPad for the same net result.