# Linq query giving me inappropriate output while counting inner child elements

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, linq

**Code Fiddle**:[Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Kid7JE)

I am trying to calculate total variations for all variants. I have list of variants with type Add and Diff and each variants contains list of subvariants and this subvariants will be either in TestOperation or TestoperationDifference.

> Method of type Add variants with its corresponding subvariants belongs
>   to TestOperation.
>
> Method of type Add variants with its corresponding subvariants belongs
>   to TestOperation.

**For eg**:Consider below variant

```
 new Variants { Id = 5231, Name = "Variant1", Type = "Diff", CategoryId = 3164,RegionId= 5202, SubVariants = new List<SubVariants>() }
```

Above variant contains below 3 subvariants:

```
new SubVariants { Id = 6556, VariantId = 5231,Name = "S1"},
new SubVariants { Id = 6557, VariantId = 5231,Name = "S2"},
new SubVariants { Id = 6558, VariantId = 5231,Name = "S3"},
```

Now as this above 3 subvariant is of Diff type so I will have their entries in TestOperationDifferenceTable like below:

```
new TestOperationDifference { Id = 7246, TestId = 5114, SourceSubVariantId = 6556, TargetSubVariantId = 6557, unmatch = 0 },
new TestOperationDifference { Id = 7247, TestId = 5114, SourceSubVariantId = 6557, TargetSubVariantId = 6558, unmatch = 0 },
```

For above 2 record of **TestOperationDifferenceTable**:

- 1st record indicates that for Variant1 and subvariant 6556 to 6557 there is no variation because unmatch is 0 so we will not have a count of 1 for variant1 with variation but now if unmatch is greater than 0 then we will have a count of 1 for variants with variation
- 2st record indicates that for Variant1 and subvariant 6557 to 6558 there is no variation because unmatch is 0 so we will not have a count of 1 for Variant1 but if unmatch is greater than 0 then we will have a count of 1 for variants with variation

**Note:** if unmatch is greater than 0 for both above records then we will have a count of 1 for variants with variation because both above records belongs to single variant only i.e Variant1.

So this is the Logic which I am trying:

```
TotalVariantswithVariantion=Calculate Total variants with variation of `TestOperation for each mock  + Calculate Total variants with variation of TestOperationDifference for each mock`
```

Problem I am getting with here:

```
 VariantId:5231 
    Type:Diff
    Variantion : No
    Count =0

    VariantId:5234
    Type:Diff
    Variantion : Yes
    Count =1

    VariantId:5236
    Type:Diff
    Variantion : Yes
    Count =1

    VariantId:5232
    Type:Add
    Variantion : No
    Count =0

    VariantId:5233
    Type:Add
    Variantion : Yes
    Count =1

    VariantId:5235
    Type:Add
    Variantion : Yes
    Count =1
    -------------------
    Total = 4
```

So total variation in all variants = 4 but I am getting 5 because my query is counting variantId 5231 also but although that variant doesn't have variantion if you look at below record where unmatch is 0 for both subvariants of variant1 then why this is getting counted:

```
new TestOperationDifference { Id = 7246, TestId = 5114, SourceSubVariantId = 6556, TargetSubVariantId = 6557, unmatch = 0 },
new TestOperationDifference { Id = 7247, TestId = 5114, SourceSubVariantId = 6557, TargetSubVariantId = 6558, unmatch = 0 },
```

Comment: I think you have counting variants for region 5202 and you don't have any relation with SubVariantID. So its counting on regionID which is always 3 in count because all SubVariants are having regionID 5202

Comment: @atul I am trying to get all tests for specific regionid but I have relationship between subvariantid of subvariant and sourcesubvariantid and targetsubvariantid and 1 to many relationship between variant and subvariant